# when calling new Date() on server running nodejs, date returns when server was started

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, openshift

On my OpenShift server with Node, my server.js has a `var currentTime = new Date()`. When this is called, I only get the time that the server was started every time. I'm just trying to write the date in something like this:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
console.log(currentTime);
res.write("[" + currentTime + "] " + "Pages: " + output[0] + ", Requests: " + output[1]);
res.end();
console.log('Response written to the web.');
```

How do I get the actual current time and not the server time?

Comment: Show the code where you are calling new Date()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you are caching currentTime at server start instead of creating a
new Date object on each request? Is your code like this?

```
var currentTime = new Date(); // Date object created at server start

function callback (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  console.log(currentTime);
  res.write("[" + currentTime + "] " + "Pages: " + output[0] + ", Requests: " + output[1]);
  res.end();
  console.log('Response written to the web.');
}

require('http').createServer(callback).listen(8080);
```

consider moving the date creation inside your callback:

```
function callback (req, res) {
  var currentTime = new Date(); // new date object created on each request
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  console.log(currentTime);
  res.write("[" + currentTime + "] " + "Pages: " + output[0] + ", Requests: " + output[1]);
  res.end();
  console.log('Response written to the web.');
}
```

Comment: I had `new Date()` outside the callback. Your solution works! Didn't know dates could be cached like that. Thanks.

I also looked into momentjs, where the actual date works outside the callback.